# fullcalendar version 1.6 language support?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to add Arabic lang to full calendar v.16 because I have Project running in this version does anybody know how to implement it in this version?

Comment: Please share some codes which you have tried so far, include the analysis done and the exact point where you are stuck. Otherwise this seems a low quality post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have already solved this but I'll write here a workaround since lang support seems not to be implemented on 1.6.x.

For example I'm changing its values in Spanish. Don't know if Arabic language will work with these, but some other languages might.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }, 

// just override these vars defined in fullcalendar.js
                monthNames:     ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Novimiembre","Diciembre"],
            monthNamesShort:["Ene","Feb","Mar","Abr","May","Jun","Jul","Ago","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dic"],
            dayNames:["Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado"],
            dayNamesShort:["Dom","Lun","Mar","Mié","Jue","Vie","Sáb"],
            buttonText:{prev:"<span class='fc-text-arrow'>&lsaquo;</span>",next:"<span class='fc-text-arrow'>&rsaquo;</span>",prevYear:"<span class='fc-text-arrow'>&laquo;</span>",nextYear:"<span class='fc-text-arrow'>&raquo;</span>",today:"hoy",month:"mes",week:"semana",day:"día"}, 

//rest of fullcalendar setting ....
```